# React chatbot optimization react-messenger-customer-chat

Tags: reactjs, optimization, chatbot, facebook-messenger

My Webpage contain a facebook chatbot component but **it become very slowly**. Google analytics from 86 decreased to 46. So It recommends the main thread load decreased...

The lazy load can help me? and if yes how? (because lazy loading concern about  subpage)

So how can reach that the element(chatbot) only load on the page if i click on it?

**or exist some other solution to this performance problem?**

( I did my chatbot to asyncChatbot (lazy loading) but bring up only 3 point by  Google Analytics. So create an other chunk in build folder, but not change to much the situation because the chatbot loading together the main page)

Comment: What you refer to by "a facebook chatbot component"? You refer to the official Customer Chat Plugin?

Comment: I mean this connect to Facebook by page and app ID. ( import MessengerCustomerChat from 'react-messenger-customer-chat'; )

Comment: You refer to some 3rd party library and not the official FB plugin then?

Comment: Thank you your answer but I little bit confused. What is the offical Customer Chat plugin? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook

Comment: import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { FacebookProvider, CustomChat } from 'react-facebook';
 
export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FacebookProvider appId="123456789" chatSupport>
        <CustomChat pageId="123456789" minimized={false}/>
      </FacebookProvider>    
    );
  }
}

Comment: I also use https://reactjsexample.com/react-component-for-messenger-customer-chat-plugin/

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MessengerCustomerChat from 'react-messenger-customer-chat';

ReactDOM.render(
  <MessengerCustomerChat
    pageId="<PAGE_ID>"
    appId="<APP_ID>"
    htmlRef="<REF_STRING>"
  />,
  document.getElementById('demo')
);

Comment: That component is just a wrapper for the official plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/